# Why is my background overlaying my main section?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background

My background is overlaying my main section, though my aside is correctly displayed.

Once I remove my background, the div I put one the main section is displayed, but the main section itself isn't affected by CSS modifications.

I'd like to know how to simply add content in the main section of my website, without having it overlayed by the background or the Aside section. Tnanks a lot !

[Here's the Codepen](http://codepen.io/zaky/pen/YyNyGW)

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>JOB</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css">
        <script type="application/javascript" src="dist/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>       
        <script type="application/javascript" src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="background.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="style.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- -- -- -- BACKGROUND -- -- -- -->
        <div id="opacity"> 
            <img src="http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/798507nycsky.jpg" alt="" class="nyc" />
        </div> 

        <aside class="Aside animated fadeInLeft">   

            <!-- -- -- -- LOGO -- -- -- -->
            <h1 class="logo">
                Firstname <br/>
                NAME <br/>
                <span class="orange">
                JOB <br/>
                Company<br/>
                </span> 
            </h1>

            <!-- -- -- -- HIRE ME ITEMS-- -- -- -->
            <div id="hireme" class="text-center">

            <!-- -- -- -- PORTFOLIO -- -- -- -->
            <h1 class="menu">Slider</h1>

            <!-- SLIDER -->
            <div id="slider" class="container"><br>
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <!-- <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    </ol> -->
                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active"><img src="" alt="Bukowski" width="460" height="345"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="" alt="Futsal" width="460" height="345"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="img/coffeeshop.jpg" alt="Coffee Shop" width="460" height="345"></div>
                    </div
                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                    <a style="margin-left: auto" class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a style="margin-right:auto" class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- -- -- -- ORANGE DOT -- -- -- -->
            <div class="puce"></div>

            <!-- -- -- -- RESUME -- -- -- -->
            <h1 class="menu">File</h1>
                <div class="bigBox boxHover hvr-underline-from-center"><p>View PDF</p></div> <br>
                <div class="resumeBox boxHover hvr-underline-from-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt resumeBoxIcon"></span></div>
                <div class="resumeBox boxHover hvr-underline-from-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print resumeBoxIcon"></span></div>
                <div class="resumeBox boxHover hvr-underline-from-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt resumeBoxIcon"></span></div>

            <!-- -- -- -- ORANGE DOT -- -- -- -->
            <div class="puce"></div>

            <!-- -- -- -- CONTACT -- -- -- -->
            <h1 class="menu">Contact</h1>
                <div class="bigBox boxHover hvr-underline-from-center"><p id="contactNumber">212-555-1234</p></div><br>
                <div class="contactBox hvr-underline-from-center"><i id="contactIcon" class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
                <div class="contactBox hvr-underline-from-center"><i id="contactIcon" class="fa fa-skype"></i></span></div>
            </div> <!-- #slider -->
            </div> <!-- #hireme -->

            <!-- -- -- -- LEGAL / CREDITS -- -- -- -->  
            <p id="footer">Credits | About</p>

        </aside>

        <main class="Main">
            <div id="redSquare">LOREM IPSUM BLA BLA BLA</div>
        </main>
    </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* HOMEPAGE BLUE FILTER EFFECT */
img.nyc {
    /*position:fixed;*/
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
#opacity {
    position : fixed;
    background-color: #1349A3;
    display:inline-block;
} 
#opacity img {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-animation: animation 1s linear;
    -moz-animation: animation 1s linear;
    -ms-animation: animation 1s linear;
    -o-animation: animation 1s linear;
    animation: animation 1s linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
}
@keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
}

.Aside {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(19, 73, 163, 0.8);
}

}
.Main {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: pink;

}

.logo{
    color : white;
    font-family : Roboto, sans serif;
    font-weight : 900;
    font-size : 2em;
    line-height : 22px;
    margin-top : 10px;
    margin-bottom : 0;
    margin-left : 10px;
}

.orange{
    color : #E9621E;
}

#hireme {
    margin-top : 50px;
}

.menu {
    color : white;
    font-family : Roboto, sans serif;
    font-weight : 900;
    font-size : 1.3em;
    line-height : 30px;
    margin-top : 0px;
    margin-bottom : 0px;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
}

#slider{
    margin-top : -15px;
    width:150px; 
    background-color : transparent;
}

.puce{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px/10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px/10px;
    border:solid 5px #E9621E;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;   
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    margin-top : 15px;
    margin-bottom : 15px;
}

.bigBox {
    background-color : white;
    color : #1349A3;
    font-family : Roboto, sans serif;
    font-weight : 900;
    font-size : 1em;
    width : 110px;
    height : 30px;
    line-height : 30px;
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    margin-top : 5px;
}

.resumeBox {
    background-color : white;
    width : 34px;
    margin-top : 5px;
  line-height : 30px;
  height : 30px;
}

.resumeBoxIcon {
    color : #1349A3;
    height : 30px;
    line-height : 30px;
}

#contactNumber {
    font-size : 0.88em;
}

.contactBox {
    background-color : white;
    width : 53px;
    height : 30px;
    line-height : 30px;
    margin-top : 5px;
}

#contactIcon {
    color : #1349A3;
    font-size : 1.5em;
    line-height : 30px;
    height:30px;
}

.fa-faat{color : #1349A3;
    font-size : 1.5em;
    line-height : 30px;
    height:30px;
}

#footer{
    color : white;
    font-size : 0.7em;
    text-align : center;
    position : fixed;
    bottom : 0;
    left : 10px;

}

#redSquare{width:500px;
height : 500px;
background-color : red;}

/* HOVER EFFECTS */
.hvr-underline-from-center{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-transform:translateZ(0);
    transform:translateZ(0);
    box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden
}
.hvr-underline-from-center:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    left:50%;
    right:50%;
    bottom:0;
    background:white;
    height:4px;
    -webkit-transition-property:left,right;
    transition-property:left,right;
    -webkit-transition-duration:.3s;
    transition-duration:.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-out;
    transition-timing-function:ease-out
}
.hvr-underline-from-center:active:before,
.hvr-underline-from-center:focus:before,
.hvr-underline-from-center:hover:before{
    left:0;
    right:0
}
```

Comment: your html is missing from the codepen

Comment: Don't know what happened... I updated it. Is it ok now ? Thanks Cocoa.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, is this what you are wanting? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVgVxj?editors=110

All I did was get rid of an extra `}` after `.Aside` and this:

```
.Main {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  /*background-color: pink;*/
  position: relative; //added this here
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted ! Thank you so much, you just made my day !

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)